# Why does my screen session still have "attached" status?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Why does my screen session still have "attached" status, when tcp/ip connection is broken?

Comment: What is wrong with your English?  Looks fine to me...

Comment: Tnx, it's not my native language :-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using sshd parametrs ClientAliveInterval, ClientAliveCountMax. Now my Attached screen sessions becomes Deatached after 15 sec in case of connection broken.